# touch move not swiping through multiple elements on slick slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slick.js

I have a vertical slick slider and I want this to swipe on multiple slides when swiping with touch action. But no matter how many slides I swipe, it slides back swiping only one slide.
Below is how I enabled my slide:
How can I swipe as many slides as user selects to swipe?

```js
$('#numbersSlider').slick({
      vertical: true,
      verticalSwiping: true,
      arrows: false,
      slidesToShow: 5,
      swipeToSlide: true
  });
```

```css
.numbers-box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    border: 3px solid gray;
    text-align: center;
}
        
#numbersSlider {
    text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 40px;
    overflow: scroll;
    height: 100%;
}
            
.slick-slide {
    padding: 8px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
 }
                
.slick-current {
    background-color: lightblue;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>


<div class="numbers-box">
 <div id="numbersSlider">
  <div class="select-number">1</div>
  <div class="select-number">2</div>
  <div class="select-number">3</div>
  <div class="select-number">4</div>
  <div class="select-number">5</div>
  <div class="select-number">6</div>
  <div class="select-number">7</div>
  <div class="select-number">8</div>
  <div class="select-number">9</div>
  <div class="select-number">10</div>
  <div class="select-number">11</div>
  <div class="select-number">12</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a known issue/bug in Slick slider: https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/188#issuecomment-131314569. There is no fix.

Comment: Is there any way I can achieve this behavior with another slider that supports vertical slides plus multiple swipe on touch?

Comment: Yeah, more than likely.

Comment: https://codepen.io/BMI/pen/ZRYeOB