# How to make Slick swipeToSlide vertically?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, slick.js

I'm trying to make a navigation vertical carousel compatible with IE11 i'm using [slick library](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick) for the carousel, i'm having some issues with swipeToSlide option which should allow me to slide to selected slide by swipe but instead it just swipe one slider by one:

[image]

Like in the image i would scroll to slide 5 but instead it  just scroll to the next slide.

Here is the code:

```js
        $(".slider").slick({
            centerMode: true,
            centerPadding: '60px',
            slidesToShow: 3,
            vertical: true,
            verticalSwiping: true,
            arrows: false,
            swipeToSlide: true,
            focusOnSelect: true,
        });
```

```css
        body {
            background: #3498db;
        }

        .menu h3 {
            background: #fff;
            color: #3498db;
            font-size: 36px;
            line-height: 100px;
            margin: 10px;
            padding: 2%;
            position: relative;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .menu h3 {
            opacity: 0.8;
            transition: all 300ms ease;
        }

        .slick-center h3 {
            -moz-transform: scale(1.08);
            -ms-transform: scale(1.08);
            -o-transform: scale(1.08);
            -webkit-transform: scale(1.08);
            color: #e67e22;
            opacity: 1;
            transform: scale(1.08);
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.js"></script>
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="menu">
            <h3>Menu 1</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="menu">
            <h3>Menu 2</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="menu">
            <h3>Menu 3</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="menu">
            <h3>Menu 4</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="menu">
            <h3>Menu 5</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Is it ok if I add a few lines to the `slick.js` file?

Comment: @user2495207 sure you can override or change the slick.js file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approximately in the line 2459 inside the `slick.js` file there is an `if` statement; `if(_.touchObject.swipeLength >= _.touchObject.minSwipe)` which have the following structure:

```
if(swipeLength>=90){  //if the swipe is more than 90
  ...
  slideCount=value;   //slide one
  ...
}else{
  ...
}
```

I added one more option, to slide two:

```
if(swipeLength>=90 && swipeLength<200){  //if 90<=swipe<200
  ...
  slideCount=value;               //slide one
  ...
}else if(swipeLength>=200) {      //if swipe>=200
  ...
  slideCount=value+1;             //slide two           
  ...
}else{
  ...
}
```

**Here is the real code:**
Original:

```
if (_.touchObject.swipeLength >= _.touchObject.minSwipe) {
direction = _.swipeDirection();

switch (direction) {
   case "left":
   case "down":
      slideCount = _.options.swipeToSlide
      ? _.checkNavigable(_.currentSlide + _.getSlideCount())
      : _.currentSlide + _.getSlideCount();

      _.currentDirection = 0;

      break;

   case "right":
   case "up":
      slideCount = _.options.swipeToSlide
      ? _.checkNavigable(_.currentSlide - _.getSlideCount())
      : _.currentSlide - _.getSlideCount();

      _.currentDirection = 1;

      break;

   default:
}

if (direction != "vertical") {
   _.slideHandler(slideCount);
   _.touchObject = {};
   _.$slider.trigger("swipe", [_, direction]);
}
} else {
if (_.touchObject.startX !== _.touchObject.curX) {
   _.slideHandler(_.currentSlide);
   _.touchObject = {};
}
```

Modified:

```
if (_.touchObject.swipeLength >= _.touchObject.minSwipe && _.touchObject.swipeLength < 200) {
  direction = _.swipeDirection();

  switch (direction) {
    case "left":
    case "down":
      slideCount = _.options.swipeToSlide
        ? _.checkNavigable(_.currentSlide + _.getSlideCount())
        : _.currentSlide + _.getSlideCount();
      _.currentDirection = 0;

      break;

    case "right":
    case "up":
      slideCount = _.options.swipeToSlide
        ? _.checkNavigable(_.currentSlide - _.getSlideCount())
        : _.currentSlide - _.getSlideCount();

      _.currentDirection = 1;

      break;

    default:
  }

  if (direction != "vertical") {
    _.slideHandler(slideCount);
    _.touchObject = {};
    _.$slider.trigger("swipe", [_, direction]);
  }
} else if (_.touchObject.swipeLength >= 200) {
  direction = _.swipeDirection();

  switch (direction) {
    case "left":
    case "down":
      slideCount = _.options.swipeToSlide
        ? _.checkNavigable(_.currentSlide + _.getSlideCount())
        : _.currentSlide + _.getSlideCount();
      slideCount++;
      _.currentDirection = 0;

      break;

    case "right":
    case "up":
      slideCount = _.options.swipeToSlide
        ? _.checkNavigable(_.currentSlide - _.getSlideCount())
        : _.currentSlide - _.getSlideCount();
      slideCount--;
      _.currentDirection = 1;

      break;

    default:
  }

  if (direction != "vertical") {
    _.slideHandler(slideCount);
    _.touchObject = {};
    _.$slider.trigger("swipe", [_, direction]);
  }
} else {
  if (_.touchObject.startX !== _.touchObject.curX) {
    _.slideHandler(_.currentSlide);
    _.touchObject = {};
  }
}
```

I hope I didn't miss anything.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is gonna help, but you can try (as I check this is working).

https://codepen.io/BMI/pen/ZRYeOB

The code here:

```
$(".slider").slick({
    asNavFor: '.nav',
    slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
    swipeToSlide: true
});

$(".nav").slick({
    asNavFor: '.slider',
    slidesToShow: 5,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    draggable:true,
    swipeToSlide: true,
    vertical: true,
    verticalSwiping: true,
    centerMode: false
});

// replace getSlideCount and getNavigableIndexes without rehosting hack

$(".nav, .slider").each(function() {
        this.slick.getSlideCount = function() {

        var _ = this,
            slidesTraversed, swipedSlide, centerOffset;
            

        centerOffset = _.options.centerMode === true ? _.slideWidth * Math.floor(_.options.slidesToShow / 2) : 0;

      if (_.options.swipeToSlide === true) {
                
            _.$slideTrack.find('.slick-slide').each(function(index, slide) {
                var offsetPoint = slide.offsetLeft,
                    outerSize = $(slide).outerWidth();
                
                if(_.options.vertical === true) {
                    offsetPoint = slide.offsetTop;
                    outerSize = $(slide).outerHeight();
                }
                if (offsetPoint - centerOffset + (outerSize / 2) > (_.swipeLeft * -1)) {
                    swipedSlide = slide;
                    return false;
                }
            });
            slidesTraversed = Math.abs($(swipedSlide).attr('data-slick-index') - _.currentSlide) || 1;
            
            return slidesTraversed;
        } else {
            return _.options.slidesToScroll;
        }

    };
    
        this.slick.getNavigableIndexes = function() {

        var _ = this,
            breakPoint = 0,
            counter = 0,
            indexes = [],
            max;

        if (_.options.infinite === false) {
            max = _.slideCount;
        } else {
            breakPoint = _.options.slideCount * -1;
            counter = _.options.slideCount * -1;
            max = _.slideCount * 2;
        }

        while (breakPoint < max) {
            indexes.push(breakPoint);
            breakPoint = counter + _.options.slidesToScroll;
            counter += _.options.slidesToScroll <= _.options.slidesToShow ? _.options.slidesToScroll : _.options.slidesToShow;
        }

        return indexes;

    };
});
```

I found this on
[touch move not swiping through multiple elements on slick slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59282781/touch-move-not-swiping-through-multiple-elements-on-slick-slider)